# How to align elements in a toolbar to left, middle, right

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

How can I have the three regions left, middle, right within a toolbar? I know that I can use `->` to trigger the right aligned container for all following items but what about center?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can archive this with a trick:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     title: 'Toolbar Fill Example',
     width: 300,
     height: 200,
     tbar : [
         'Item 1',
         { xtype: 'tbfill' },
         'Item 4',
         { xtype: 'tbfill' },
         'Item 2'
     ],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/11/)**

Note that:

```
[
    'Item 1',
    '->',
    'Item 4',
    '->',
    'Item 2'
]
```

is working all the same.

**How it work**

`->` or it's xtype `tbfill` is nothing more than a empty Component with a `flex: 1` configuration.

Comment: This will only keep the middle item centered assuming they all have the same width. You can make the last item, "Item 10102598" and you will see that the middle item is not centered anymore.

Comment: + for explaining xtype of ->

Answer (score 5):

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     title: 'Toolbar Fill Example',
     width: 300,
     height: 200,
     tbarCfg:{
          buttonAlign:'center'  //for center align
         // buttonAlign:'left' //for left align
         // buttonAlign:'right' //for right align
     },
     tbar : [
         'Item 1',
         { xtype: 'tbfill' },
         'Item 4',
         { xtype: 'tbfill' },
         'Item 2'
     ],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
For Right:    
bbar: ['->',{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'xyz',

                }]

For Left:    
bbar: ['<-',{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'xyz',

                }]
```

Answer (score 2):

dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        buttonAlign:'center',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            text: 'Docked to the top'
        }]
    }]